# How to reference a style from another module with the same name as the one in the app module?

Tags: android

I have two modules in my project:

- Module A -> app module
- Module B -> lib module

Module A uses Module B.

I have this `<style>` on Module A

```
<style name="Widget.TextView.Blah" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

and this `<style>` on Module B

```
<style name="Widget.TextView.Blah" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
    <item name="maxLines">1</item>
</style>
```

Both styles have the same name.

I'm creating an xml layout in Module A, where in this xml I create a `TextView` field that needs Module's B `Widget.TextView.Blah` style. How can I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.TextView.Blah" 
        android:text="I want to reference Module's B style. How can I achieve this?"/>

</FrameLayout>
```